# Program not exiting for loop after returning?

Tags: c++, for-loop, token

This program is suppose to identify tokens from an input file. Here is some of the input file

Test = Exam

The program should read in a line of text and identify the separate "phrases" that appear. For example the first line would produce the output "Test" -> IDENTIFIER, "=" -> ASSIGNMENT OPERATOR, "Exam" -> IDENTIFIER. Each line is a separate input to be read. I have a for loop to check the characters in the string to see what type of identifier it might be. For some reason, my program will not exit the for loop in my token type function. I have tried debugging but I am extremely confused where the program is getting stuck. I threw some cout statements in the program to maybe help identify the issue. For some reason the input is not getting past the first word "Test". It will read it in 3-5 times and then just error out.

Here is the current output (The program wouldn't normally output each individual character and index #, I just included it to make it possibly easier to follow along and locate the error)

```
File Opened
Test = Exam
0 T e s t
1 T e s t
2 T e s t
3 T e s t
4
5
6
7 T e s t
 E x a m
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

const int SIZE = 100;

enum Token { IDENTIFIER, ARITHMETIC, RELATIONAL, LOGICAL, COMPOUND, 
         ASSIGNMENT, INTEGER, ILLEGAL, ENDLINE };

void getData(ifstream& inData, char data[]);
Token getTokenType(char data[], Token type[], char subStr[][SIZE], int index);
void displayData(char data[], Token type[], char subStr[][SIZE]);
void displayType(Token type[], int index);

int main()
{
    char input[SIZE], subString[SIZE][SIZE];
    Token type[SIZE];
    ifstream inFile;
    ofstream outFile;

    inFile.open("mp5in.txt");

    if (inFile)
        cout << "File Opened" << endl << endl;
    else
        cout << "File Failed to Open" << endl << endl;

    getData(inFile, input);

    while (inFile)
    {       
        for (int i = 0; type[i] != ENDLINE; i++)
        {
            cout << i << " ";
            type[i] = getTokenType(input, type, subString, i);
            cout << endl;
        }

        displayData(input, type, subString);

        getData(inFile, input);
    }

    inFile.close();

    return 0;
 }

void getData(ifstream& inData, char data[])
{
    int i = 0;

    while (inData && data[i] != '\n')
    {
        inData.get(data[i]); 
        cout << data[i];

        if (data[i] == '\n')
            break;

        i++;
    }

}

Token getTokenType(char data[], Token type[], char subStr[][SIZE], int index)
{
    int size = index;
    int row = index, col = index;
    bool valid = true, end = false;

    for (int i = index; data[i] != '\n'; i += size)
    {
        if (isalpha(data[col]))
        {
            for (col = 0; subStr[row][col] != ' '; col++)
            {
                subStr[row][col] = data[col];
                cout << subStr[row][col] << " ";

                if ((!isalpha(subStr[row][col]) || !isdigit(subStr[row][col])) && 
                        subStr[row][col] != '_')
                    valid = false;
                if (subStr[row][col] == ' ' && !valid)
                    return ILLEGAL;
                else if (subStr [row][col] == ' ' && valid)
                    return IDENTIFIER;
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Not all the program is here. I left it out as the program does not currently get that far along in the program.

Comment: Sorry for the unusual indentation, trying to post the code into the question was extremely tedious

Comment: Unfortunately, because the shown code fails to meet all requirements for [mre], nobody will be able to help you. For more information, see [ask].

Comment: ***trying to post the code into the question was extremely tedious*** Normally all is needed is to 1. Copy and paste from your IDE, 2. Select the text, 3. Use the `{}` button to form a code block. If that does not work correctly use [http://format.krzaq.cc/](http://format.krzaq.cc/) to fix the formatting first and repeat the steps.

Comment: Take care: when a function promises to return a value it must ALWAYS return a value. `for (int i = index; data[i] != '\n'; i += size)` allows the function to exit without returning a value.

Comment: I didn't look too much into your code as it isn't a minimal reproducible example but `for (int i = index; data[i] != '\n'; i += size)` seems very odd. Why do you increment in size? Why is '\n' your stopping criteria? Are you sure you're not accessing past the arrays limit and reading memory mambo-jambo?